# How to pass an Altair graph from one Flask route to another?

Tags: python, json, flask, graph, altair

I am very new to Flask. I am developing a web app to show graphs. One of the graphs I need to show is using Altair.

```py
from altair import layer

def create_altair(anomaly_id):
    .
    .
    .
    graph = (
        layer(interval, All, normals, anomalies, current_anomaly)
        .properties(width=870, height=450)
        .configure_title(fontSize=20)
    )

    return graph.to_json(), one_anomaly
```

```py
@App.route("/anomaly/<int:anomaly_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def anomaly(anomaly_id):

    graph, current_anomaly = create_altair(anomaly_id)
    if """form is valide, it will be input to the database""":
        anomaly_id += 1
        return redirect(
            url_for(
                "anomaly",
                title="Anomaly Dectection",
                anomaly_id=anomaly_id,
                form=form,
                single_anomaly=current_anomaly,
                graph=graph,
            )
        )

    return render_template(
        "anomaly.html",
        title="Anomaly Dectection",
        anomaly_id=anomaly_id,
        form=form,
        single_anomaly=current_anomaly,
        graph=graph,
    )
```

Then I need to pass the graph that I got from the anomaly route to the Altair chart route below. I tried using variable in the URL link (as shown in this post) and flask.session. But both don’t work. Are these the right methods to use? Or are there other methods that I haven’t explored? Thank you in advance!

```py
########################
# Altair Routes
########################

@App.route("/chart/anomaly/<string:graph>")
def anomaly_chart(graph):
    return graph
```

```html
<!-- Render Charts -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function parse(url, div) {
        var opt = {
            mode: "vega-lite",
            renderer: "svg",
            actions: { export: true, source: false, editor: false }
        };

        vegaEmbed("#" + div, url, opt, function (error, result) {
            // result.view is the Vega View, url is the original Vega-Lite specification
            vegaTooltip.vegaLite(result.view, url);
        });
    }
    parse("/chart/anomaly/" + {{ graph }}, "pred");

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by saving the json file on local and retrieve this local file from another flask route.